# Need to center a table within a fieldset within a form

Tags: html, css

I had a quick HTML/CSS question I hope someone could help me with!

I am trying to learn the specifics of CSS in an online course. I am trying to do a very specific alignment with CSS within a form within a fieldset within a table. I need to have a fieldset split down the middle, and have the label directly on the left, and the input of the form directly on the right. I uploaded 2 pictures: what I have so far and what I am hoping to get, to give a visualization of what I am trying to achieve.

For anyone versed in CSS I am sure this is very easy but it's confusing me. Was just hoping to get some direction!

What I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zVe1.jpg

What I want to get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pobkb.jpg

Ignore the repetitive code/names in the first image, I am just worried about the alignment of the labels, inputs and buttons.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration Information</legend>
                <table>
                   <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
            <legend>Submit Your Registration</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit"></td>
                        <td><input type="reset"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #A8F89C;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

table {
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed; 
}

fieldset {
    width: 410px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

legend {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

label {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #06127D;
}

td label {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 7px;
}

td input {
    padding-left: 7px;
}

form input {
    width: 140px;
}

label input[type="radio"] {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #201E1C;
}

button {
    width: 75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgb(28,67,14);
}
```

Thank you so much for any help!!!

Comment: align all the text in the labels to right...

Comment: I already had text-align: right; in the "label" class, and I added it to the "td label" class as well. It didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

I just have read your requirement what you want to get.

You can use below mentioned css to get layout like this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pobkb.jpg

```
<style>
fieldset,table{
   width:100%
}
td{
   width:50%;
}
tbody tr td:first-child{
   text-align:right;
   padding-right:20px;
}
```

I hope it will usefull for you as per your need.

Thanks

Comment: If it is worked for you will you please accept as answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

My idea would add this CSS to (Because label doesn't fill the entire width of the td as label is not a block level element)

```
td label{
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:right;
}
```

or if you prefer you could something like this too, add

```
td {
    text-align: right
}
```

but it moves all the td elements to right.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet below

Take out the border if needed

```css
body {
  background-color: #A8F89C;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

fieldset {
  width: 410px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

legend {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #06127D;
}

td label {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

td input {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

form input {
  width: 140px;
}

label input[type="radio"] {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #201E1C;
}

button {
  width: 75px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(28, 67, 14);
}

table {
  border: solid red;
  display: inline-table;
}

fieldset {
  border: solid blue;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <title>Test 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">

</head>



<body>

  <form>
    <fieldset>

      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>

      <legend>Registration Information</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>First Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>

      <legend>Submit Your Registration</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="submit">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="reset">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all using div maybe easier to use ..I have modify a bit of your html where i get rid of the tr and td and use div .Hope this help

`<div align = "center">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text">
           </div>`

[image: I just make the div to center]